# Pandas : make a new column from existing column that ends with character

Tags: python, pandas

[Here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGqBF.png)

I need to select multiple strings that ends with ['edit'] make new column name 'state' from this dataframe.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df['state'] = df.loc[df['YourCol'].str.endswith('[edit]'), 'YourCol']
```

Just replace `YourCol` with the column you're working with, and `df` with the name of your `dataframe`. Note that where it doesn't end with `[edit]`, you will get `NaN` values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use the "[edit]" rows not just as a separate column, instead map them to the schools below them, so that you'd end up with something like this:

```
School                                           State

Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]    Alaska
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)          Arizona
Tempe (Arizona State University)                 Arizona
Tucson (University of Arizona)                   Arizona
Arkadelphia (Henderson State University, ...)    Arkansas
```

If that's the case, you can use a combination of Nicolas Gervais's answer with pandas' [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['State'] = df[df['YourCol'].str.endswith('[edit]')]['YourCol']
df['State'] = df['State'].fillna(method='ffill') # Forward-fills the states
df = df.drop(df[df['YourCol'].str.endswith('[edit]')]) # Drop the "header" rows
df['State'] = df['State'].str.slice_replace(start=-6) # Remove "[edit]" from the end of the state names
```